# Are there any PHP based fleet & route management software out there?

Tags: php

I am looking for a software that:

- is used for managing your fleet.
- find best routes for many stops for your cars/trucks.
- is customizable and based on PHP - or has at least SQL server in the background.

I found [this page](http://www.capterra.com/fleet-management-software/) but most of this software looks really standard in terms of Windows installation software that you can not run on a web server (with standardized APIs).

Do you need any more information for a recommendation? Or just point me to a good Google search result - actually I do not know how to find something appropriate. I even do not know which tags are good for such question.

Comment: Did you look at https://sourceforge.net/directory/os:windows/?q=fleet%20vehicle%20management  and maybe a similar search on GitHub?